# How to implement the "New Document" window like Pages app does?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

As a OS X user, you must be quite familiar with the "New Documents" window when you start some Apple's apps, like Pages.

[image]

This window is so common, that I thought it must be some system-provided window, am I right?

I tried to mimic the window, and it turns out to be quite tedious. As a developer, I have to first create a finder-like browser view with list-style selection support. Also, iCloud integration is quite difficult not to mention search support.

So, my question is how can I implement this window, is there any documentation writing about this window? Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Look at NSDocument. That is Apple's suggested way of creating document-based apps. You create a subclass of NSDocument to handle tasks specific to your data format, and the superclass handles all the heavy lifting, including iCloud support. I haven't used it myself, but I know that it handles open and save chores, so that's probably where the panel is coming from.

Comment: Umm, I do use NSDocument, but that new document window doesn't seem to come out of box...

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, to get this window, all I need to do is to enable iCloud support in `Capabilities` tab of project properties page.

A little heads up: doesn't work for Swift in Xcode6 Beta. I don't know why to be frankly. And it took me a day to searching around...